# How to extract the text from a weird element type using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

After I select a day with the pop-up date picker, the line is filled with the date like this:

[image: Text]

I need this text. I tried using this:

```
    iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)

    date = iframe.text
```

Except that this code doesn't work because the text is not inside the element (I still don't know exactly why). I searched a bit and I found out that it's something called a ShadowRoot element and sometimes it's extractable but sometimes it's not.

This is what the element HTML looks like in Chrome dev tools:

[image: Text]

And this is what it looks like in Safari. Note the **difference**:

[image: Text]

Of course, I can't use this because it's not **actually** different from Chrome.

**I need a way to get the date from this box. Any help will be highly appreciated!**

Comment: can you share a link to that web page?

Comment: without real URL for this page there is answer.

Comment: User name and password are needed to reach the URL

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath:
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@id='appointments_consultate']//following::div").text

If this is not working, can you go a level up on your webelement in Chrome browser and share the screenshot